# How to make blur an item in drop down if it is already present in gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

in my application i have two drop downs where in one drop down i need to make blur those days if they are present for particular ddl how can i do this

```
protected void ddlname_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlname.SelectedItem.Text == "--Select--")
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "";
            grdname.Visible = false;
                      }
        else
        {
            grdname.Visible = true;
            BindGrid();
        }
    }
```

here in this event i need to blur the days if they are already given for that batch if not they should be displayed how can i do this

Comment: You can't do it during OnDataBinding because the data has not been bound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use dropdownlist databound event and apply your css

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1"  runat="server"            
 OnDataBound="DropDownList1_DataBound"> </asp:DropDownList>




   protected void DropDownList1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    foreach(ListItem myItem in DropDownList1.Items)
    {
          myItem.Attributes.Add("style","background-color:blue"); 
     }
   }
```

Comment: MyItems.Attributes.Add("style","background-color:blue");